# Бесконечный цикл внутри потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, while

Нужно реализовать бесконечный цикл внутри потока. В коде реализовано меню с запуском бесконечного цикла при выборе пункта. Надо сделать так, чтобы при выборе этого пункта цикл запускался в отдельном потоке(без функции завершения) и меню опять давало выбор пункта, не зависая. Код:

```
    cout << "\n [?] Choose you functions: "; cin >> menuc;
Sleep(1000);

if (menuc == 1) {
    cout << "\n [+] AMMO is enabled!" << endl;
    enAmmo();
}
```

Код enAmmo():

```
void enAmmo() {
while (true) {
    rAmmo();
    lAmmo();
}
```

Прошу привести пример кода, как это реализовать.

Comment: вам нужен или WinAPI с `CreateThread` или стандартная библиотека с `std::thread` на выбор

Comment: В дополнение к совету выше, помимо документации по `std::thread` советую почитать про то, как вообще устроены потоки. И также про синхронизацию потоков https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/549814/